# Accessing the variable inside nested function python

Tags: python, global-variables, local-variables, class-variables, nested-function

I am trying to access the variable which is inside a class and also inside nested function. I am trying to access that variable into another class but after using `'global'` i have no luck in accessing it. Can anyone help 
Here is the code

```
class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        #Some code


    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        #Some code

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        #Some code


class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        def click():
            entered_text=textentry.get()
            #Some code

class PageTwo(StartPage,PageOne):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        #Some code

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

I am trying to access `entered_text` which is present inside `PageOne` class into `PageTwo` class inside the `__init__` method

Regards 
Sagar

Comment: Could you make a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: E.g. user `pass` instead of `#some code` and make minimal example without the unnecessary tk reference.

Answer (score 0):

First, why is `click()` defined inside the **init** method?

Also, as long as `click()` doesn't return the *`entered_text`* value (so that you can store it's output in another variable, or it doesn't update a class property (like if you'd have a *`self.entered_text`* var, then it just exists during the function's very execution.

Here's what I mean:

#### Example 1:

```
class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

    def click():
        entered_text = textentry.get()
        return entered_text

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_instance = PageOne()
    my_instance.click()
    print(my_instane.entered_text)
```

#### Example 2:

```
class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
         self.entered_text = str()

    def click():
        self.entered_text = textentry.get()
```

Comment: Thanks for this arkwright. I got a idea of how to use 'self' but the click() should be present inside the __init__  because i have made some variable initialisation inside the constructor